# How to install cordova version 1.5 on mac using npm command?

Tags: macos, cordova, cordova-3

I am able to download cordova using the following command

sudo npm install -g cordova.

But it downloads the latest version i.e version 3.4 which is not compatible with my xcode version which is 3.2. So I want to download version 1.5 of cordova. How to download version 1.5 of cordova using the above command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo npm install -g cordova@VERSION_NO

these are the available versions

```
  ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.0.5","0.0.6","0.0.7","0.0.8","0.0.9","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4","0.1.5","0.1.6","0.1.7","0.1.8","0.1.9","0.1.10","0.1.11","0.1.12","0.1.13","0.1.14","2.2.0","2.3.0","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","2.3.5","2.3.6","2.4.0","2.4.1","2.4.2","2.4.3","2.4.4","2.4.5","2.4.6","2.4.7","2.4.8","2.4.9","2.4.10","2.5.0","2.5.2","2.5.3","2.5.4","2.5.5","2.6.0","2.6.1","2.6.2","2.7.0-rc.1","2.7.1-rc.1","2.7.2","2.7.3","2.7.4","2.8.0","2.8.1","2.8.2","2.8.3","2.8.4","2.8.5","2.8.6","2.8.7","2.8.8","2.8.9","2.8.10","2.8.11","2.8.12","2.8.13","2.8.14","2.8.15","2.8.16","2.8.17","2.8.18","2.8.19","2.8.20","2.8.21","2.8.22","2.8.23","2.8.24","2.8.25","2.9.0","2.9.1","2.9.2","2.9.3","2.9.4","2.9.5","2.9.6","2.9.7","3.0.0-rc1","3.0.0-rc1-1","3.0.0-rc1-3","3.0.0","3.0.1","3.0.2","3.0.3","3.0.4","3.0.5","3.0.6","3.0.7","3.0.8","3.0.9","3.0.10","3.1.0-0.1.0","3.1.0-0.2.0","3.2.0-rc.1","3.2.0-0.1.0","3.2.0-0.2.0","3.2.0-0.3.0","3.2.0-0.4.0","3.3.0-rc.1","3.3.0-0.1.1","3.3.1-0.1.2","2.9.0-rc1","3.3.1-0.3.0","3.3.1-0.3.1","3.3.1-0.4.1","3.3.1-0.4.2","3.4.0-0.1.0","3.4.0-0.1.1","3.4.0-0.1.2","3.4.0-0.1.3"]
```

so if i had to install version 0.0.4 
I would go with

```
 sudo npm install -g cordova@0.0.4
```

Comment: type "npm view cordova versions" to see all available versions

Answer (score 1):

sudo npm install phonegap@1.5.* -g